# Can wavefunctions always be separated into a product of spatial and spin parts?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, quantum-spin, schroedinger-equation, hydrogen

Firstly, I wanted to check. Can wavefunctions exist that are not in the form $\psi = \psi_{\mbox{spatial}}\times\psi_{\mbox{spin}}$?

I am assuming you can have situations that are dependent on spin and so get a situation where a particle is either 'in position A and spin up' or 'in position down and spin down' so $|\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}(|A\uparrow\rangle+ |B\downarrow\rangle)$, and thus not able to be separated.

Also I wanted to check specifically that once you include spin-orbit coupling, the hydrogen atom eigenstates can no longer be in the form $\psi = \psi_{\mbox{spatial}}\times\psi_{\mbox{spin}}$. Wikipedia says that in this case the good quantum numbers can no longer be $l,j,s, m_l,m_s$ (which makes sense since e.g. $S_z$ does not commute with $L\cdot S$) but must instead be $l,j,s,m_j$.

Therefore I would assume there could theoretically exist eigenstates with fixed $m_j$ but varying correlated combinations of $m_s$ and $m_l$ e.g. $|m_l=+1, m_s=0\rangle$ and $|m_l=0, m_s=+1\rangle$ (which indeed have fixed $l,j,s,m_j$, but cannot be separated into spatial and spin parts). Is this correct, or is there a reason why the wavefunction can still be separated into these parts?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/468581. Note what Emilio says in the comments about energy eigenstates